# I successfully am able to run a Hello World program in C++, but I can't see and output. Where is it?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am a complete beginner.  I just downloaded xCode today.  Here is a screenshot of what I have:

[image]

As you can see, I successfully ran the program, however, I can't see any out put anywhere.  Where is it and how do I see it?

Comment: We have code formatting here for a reason. Screenshots are hard to read/copy, more so when they're not even in the post.

Comment: @chris: for most cases I'd agree, but in this instance, I think the screenshot is fair enough. As for not being "in" the post, that privilege takes more rep than user1443548 has so far...

Comment: I see a successful _build_ but nothing anywhere indicates that it's been _run_...

Comment: @sarnold, you need rep to put an image in? And I do guess the image does give the hint that it hasn't been run. I never knew that one. Anyway, are you sure you ran it, not just built it?

Comment: @chris: yeah, [posting images requires ten points](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user). (All in all probably for the best -- if an image looks good, typically some high-rep user will add it in an edit in a minute or two anyhow.)

Answer (score 5):

It does not look like the program has run at all, only built. The status up at the top says *build* succeeded, not *run* succeeded. Command-R will run the program.

Here is what it will look like when you run the program:
[image: Finished running]

Also you can use the Log Navigator to go and see results from previous build and debug sessions.
[image: Log Navigator]

You will often see tutorial programs written for Windows where the program ends with asking the user for input. The reason for this is that the console model on Windows has the program owning the console window, so the window will disappear as soon as the program exits. So by asking for input as the last thing the program will keep running until the user gives it that input, whereupon it the program will complete and the console window will disappear.

Non-Windows platforms don't behave this way and generally do not require such code.

Answer (score 3):

Put a breakpoint at the return statement or a getchar() before return.
The reason you're not seeing the output is because the console closes when the program exits.
So the above points prevent the program from ending.

Comment: Does xcode really not pause it for you like other IDEs? I haven't seen an IDE that doesn't.

Comment: From what I've seen when other people are using it, it does for them. Did it change in a version?

Comment: i added getchar() but nothing changed.  i'm supposed to see Hello World! show up somewhere, right?

Comment: Running it by pressing Ctrl+F5 will pause, but F5 does not.

Comment: @Superman, Ohh that makes sense. I always did that for the short time that I used it before switching, and I guess most other people in the class did as well.

Comment: I have done both of your suggestions, but I still cannot see an output

Comment: This answer has no relevance to Xcode. Nor do the VS shortcuts ctrl-F5 and F5.